Extending a function domain into a closure.
From Munkres' Topology section on continuous functions, the theorem of interest is the following equivalency:
Given topological spaces $(X,\mathscr{T}_X)$, $(Y,\mathscr{T}_Y)$

$f:X\to Y$ is continuous
For every subset $A\subseteq X$, $f(\bar{A})\subseteq \overline{f(A)}$

If we then consider the function $f:(0,1)\subsetneq\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R} := f:x\mapsto\frac{1}{x}$ which is continuous, how does one evaluate the 2nd implication because $\overline{(0,1)}=[0,1]$ but we'll have a problem at $f(0)$?

In the theorem statement, the closure of $A$ is taken in the ambient space $X$.  In your example, $X = (0, 1)$ (and the topology is the subspace topology inherited from the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$).  The closure of $(0, 1)$ in $X$ is $(0, 1)$, not $[0, 1]$, so no problem arises.
A little more generally, the definition of the subspace topology gives us that in your example, for any $A \subseteq (0, 1)$, $\overline{A} = cl(A) \cap (0, 1)$, where $cl(A)$ is the closure of $A$ in $\mathbb{R}$.  The theorem doesn't say anything about extending the domain of $f$, so nothing outside of $X$ is relevant on the domain side.

This is exactly correct. $+1$
